# Filter DatagridView without datasource

Tags: vb.net, filter, datagridview, restsharp

I'm trying to filter a manually loaded datagridview via code by a textbox. It doesn't work, it tells me System.NullReferenceException.

```
Private Sub Frm_Canciones_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Dgv_canciones.Rows.Clear()

    Dim request As New RestRequest("canciones", DataFormat.Json)

    ClienteRest.Cabeceras(request)

    Dim response = ClienteRest.cliente.Get(request)

    Dim respuesta As New JObject(CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content), JObject))

    For Each token As JToken In respuesta.SelectToken("data")
        Dim song As Cancion = token.ToObject(Of Cancion)

        Me.Dgv_canciones.Rows.Insert(Me.Dgv_canciones.NewRowIndex, song.id, song.getTituloCompleto(), song.duracion, song.url, song.archivo)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Txt_buscar_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Txt_buscar.TextChanged
    If Me.Txt_buscar.Text.Length > 3 Then
        Dim campo As String = "cancion"

        Try
            CType(Me.Dgv_canciones.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", campo, Me.Txt_buscar.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "Error!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You never set a DataTable as the DGV's DataSource, so `CType(Me.Dgv_canciones.DataSource, DataTable)` won't get you much, as you're already aware of. You didn't show the JSON, but there's a chance you can deserialize to a DataTable directly.

Comment: The question is how can I only display the rows that match the inserted text in a text box if the datagridview is filled by loop with insert method and has no associated datasource or datatable.

Comment: Fill a `BindingList<class>` using a class object that can describe the values you want to show in your DGV, use the BindingList as the DataSource of a BindingSource, set the BindingSource as the DataSource of your DGV the use the BindingSource methods to filter, order etc. the DGV. Or, fill a DataTable, which provides ~the same tools. Controls are just **presenters** (tools that present the data), not data storage/handler facilities. You need to separate your data from the View, if you want to work efficiently. Otherwise, it's a constant search for a new *hack*.

Comment: Thanks, @Jimi. I have done it with your last example. I have just published the solution that I have applied and it is 100% functional. Thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved it in the following way. I have created a datatable with the fields that I need for this gridview. Although, firstly I have created a global DataTable on my form.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("id", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("cancion", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("duracion", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("url", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("archivo", GetType(String))
```

In the loop, instead of using the insert method of the datagridview, I have filled the datatable with the received data.

```
    For Each token As JToken In respuesta.SelectToken("data")
        Dim song As Cancion = token.ToObject(Of Cancion)

        dt.Rows.Add(song.id.ToString, song.getTituloCompleto().ToString, song.duracion.ToString, song.url.ToString, song.archivo.ToString)

    Next
```

I have then mapped the resulting DataTable to my form's global DataTable for later use. And I have assigned as DataSource of the DataGridView the DataTable Global.

```
    Me.GridTable = dt
    Me.Dgv_canciones.DataSource = Me.GridTable
```

Finally, in the TextChanged event of the TextBox, I have placed a conditional so that it only searches if the user has typed at least 3 characters in the text field. If you have typed less, it loads the entire list of songs and if you have typed more it loads the search results.

```
    If Me.Txt_buscar.Text.Length > 2 Then
        Dim campo As String = "cancion"

        Try
            Dim filter As String = String.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", campo, Me.Txt_buscar.Text)
            GridTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Coño, no puedo buscar!!! Vaya mierda de programador está hecho el Zeko!!!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, "Coño!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    ElseIf Me.Txt_buscar.Text.Length < 2 Then
        DirectCast(Me.Dgv_canciones.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Empty
    End If
```

And here I leave you the complete corrected and functional code.

```
Public Class Frm_Canciones

Dim GridTable As DataTable

Private Sub Frm_Canciones_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Dgv_canciones.Rows.Clear()

    Dim request As New RestRequest("canciones", DataFormat.Json)

    ClienteRest.Cabeceras(request)

    Dim response = ClienteRest.cliente.Get(request)

    Dim respuesta As New JObject(CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content), JObject))


    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("id", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("cancion", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("duracion", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("url", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("archivo", GetType(String))

    For Each token As JToken In respuesta.SelectToken("data")
        Dim song As Cancion = token.ToObject(Of Cancion)

        dt.Rows.Add(song.id.ToString, song.getTituloCompleto().ToString, song.duracion.ToString, song.url.ToString, song.archivo.ToString)

    Next

    Me.GridTable = dt
    Me.Dgv_canciones.DataSource = Me.GridTable

End Sub

Private Sub Txt_buscar_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Txt_buscar.TextChanged
    If Me.Txt_buscar.Text.Length > 2 Then
        Dim campo As String = "cancion"

        Try
            Dim filter As String = String.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", campo, Me.Txt_buscar.Text)
            GridTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Coño, no puedo buscar!!! Vaya mierda de programador está hecho el Zeko!!!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, "Coño!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    ElseIf Me.Txt_buscar.Text.Length < 2 Then
        DirectCast(Me.Dgv_canciones.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Frm_Canciones_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Dgv_canciones_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Dgv_canciones.CellDoubleClick
    If (Me.Dgv_canciones.CurrentRow.Index + 1) < Me.Dgv_canciones.Rows.Count Then
        Dim fPrograma As New Frm_programa

        Helpers.currentCancion = New Cancion(Me.Dgv_canciones.Rows.Item(Me.Dgv_canciones.CurrentRow.Index).Cells.Item(0).Value)

        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: All right. There's one thing you have to change: you don't need or want to create a new DataView. Remove this: `Dim FilterData As New DataView(Me.GridTable)`. Use the `DataTable.DefaultView`: e.g., `dim filter = String.Format(...)  DirectCast(Dgv_canciones.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filter`. To remove the filter, just `DirectCast(Dgv_canciones.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.empty`. OR, since you stored the DataTable, `GridTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter`, which is the same thing, since you're pointing to the same object.

Comment: Well, in the end I have chosen to improve the code with your suggestion.
`Dim filter As String = String.Format ("[{0}] LIKE '% {1}%'", field, Me.Txt_buscar.Text)
GridTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter`